# Javadoc methods of a protected class

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I have a `protected` class that is extended by a `public` class. The `protected` class contains a number of `public` methods.

When Javadoc is generated for `public` visibility, the inherited methods do not appear in the documentation of the `public` class.

I would like for the inherited methods to appear in the method summary of the extending class when generating Javadoc for `public` visibility. My reasoning is that if the base class isn't being documented (due to protected), then any `public` class that extends it should have those methods in its method summary.

Is there some way of annotating these methods or arguments to javadoc that would accomplish this?

Comment: Does `javadoc -protected` not work?

Comment: That causes Javadoc to be generated for the protected class.

Answer (score 0):

The `@inheritDoc` javadoc annotation should be worth a try.

I have not tried this explicitly, but if I were you I would read  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#inheritingcomments) page completely.

Comment: This would only work if the `public` class overrode the methods from the `protected` class; in which case it wouldn't be necessary because this is the automatic behaviour.